# How should I esteem the measurement error using an instrument with high precision and low accuracy?

Tags: error-analysis, instrument

I was performing an experiment about the Beer–Lambert law using a luxmeter I bought online. In the user manual it's stated it has "$Accuracy: \pm\,3\%\,reading\pm\,8\,digits$". During the first measurement of light exposure I registrated all the values returned by the instrument and they were distributed like a Gaussian with $mean=294\,\,\,\sigma=0.4$. I kept making measurements and then plotted a graph using as y-values the means and the means standard deviations and found out that they were light years away from my theoric model. Put it simply, the values returned by the instrument always fluctuated above or below the expected value and therefore taking the mean of the values of each measurement was pretty useless, so how should I assign a final value to each measurement? I thought that the most reasonable option was $mean\pm Accuracy$ ignoring this way the absurdly small standard deviation of each mean. Is it a good solution or there are more refined ways to deal with this kind of cases?

Comment: You would combine systematic (machine accuracy) and random (standard deviation) error https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89174/how-to-sum-uncertainties-systematic-and-random#89195

Comment: "esteem"? What do you mean by "esteem"? "Esteem" is not usually applied to measurement errors, but to people. I think you may mean "regard?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best reference for these issues is the BIPM Guide to Uncertainty in Measurement:

https://www.iso.org/sites/JCGM/GUM/JCGM100/C045315e-html/C045315e.html?csnumber=50461

https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/2071204/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf

The approach is to estimate all sources of uncertainty and combine them into a combined standard uncertainty. If your sources of uncertainty are uncorrelated then you simply add the variances to get the combined uncertainty squared.

Here you have the statistically measured uncertainty $u_s = 0.4$ and the instrument uncertainty $u_i = 294 \times 3 \ \% = 8.8$. So your combined standard uncertainty (assuming these to be the only sources of uncertainty) would be $u_c=\sqrt{u_s^2 + u_i^2}=\sqrt{77.8+0.16} = 8.8$